# What is "uses" directive in github actions used for?

Tags: github, github-actions

I can't event find it in documentation - `uses`. For what is it used? Where I can read about this command?

Answer (score 5):

`uses` is used to select an action that is already defined and can be reused. It can be defined in the same repository, a public repository or the Docker hub.

Below is from the GitHub Actions [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses) regarding `uses` (ie **jobs.{job_id}.steps.uses**) keyword

> Selects an action to run as part of a step in your job. An action is a
>   reusable unit of code. You can use an action defined in the same
>   repository as the workflow, a public repository, or in a published
>   Docker container image.

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    steps:
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
```

When you see the above config for a GitHub action, it means it uses the **v1** version of GitHub action defined in the repository [setup-java](https://github.com/actions/setup-java)

Comment: What does github do in order to run perform the `setup-java` action?

Comment: @MehdiCharife [setup-java](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) action has its source code on Github too.