# What does github actions "uses: ./" do?

Tags: github-actions

Does anyone know what this does ?

```
uses: ./
```

I see it used in quite a few places but cannot seem to find any reference for it.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045478/what-is-uses-directive-in-github-actions-used-for?rq=3

Comment: This question is in no way a duplicate of that question @MehdiCharife

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uses` keyword of github actions is used to specify the action that should be executed as part of a workflow. The `./` value tells GitHub to use the action defined in the current repository, rather than referencing a pre-built action.

It's also possible to specify the path to the action within the repository, rather than using `./`. For example:

```
steps:
  - uses: ./path
    with:
      parameter1: value1
      parameter2: value2
```

This would execute the action located at ./path within the repository.

Comment: By action do you mean a command like `apt` or `npm`  or `restart`?